# Using LoadRunner to Test Server Processes

Tags: web-services, ibm-mq, performance-testing, loadrunner

We currently use LoadRunner for performance testing our web apps, but we also have some server side processes we need to test.

### Background:

We call these processes our "engines". One engine receives messages by polling an IBM WebSpere MQ queue for messages. It takes a message off the queue, processes it, and puts the result on an outbound queue. We currently test this engine via a TCL script that reads a file that contains the messages, puts the messages on the inbound queue, then polls the outbound queue for the results.

The other engine receives messages via a web service. The web service writes the message to a table in our database. The engine polls the database table for new messages, takes a message and processes it, and puts the result back into the database. We currently test this engine via a VBScript script that reads a file that contains the messages, sends the message to the web service, then keeps querying the web service for the result unitl it's ready.

### Question:

We'd like to do away with the TCL and VBScript scripts and standardize on LoadRunner so that we have one tool to manage all our performance tests.

1. I know LoadRunner supports a Web Services protocol "out of the box", but I'm not sure how to use it. Does anyone know of any examples of how to use LoadRunner to test a web service?
2. Does LoadRunner have a protocol for MQ? Is it possible to use a LoadRunner Vuser to drive load (put messages) into an MQ queue? Would we need to purchase something from HP or some other vendor to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an add-in for LoadRunner in the incuded software to interface with MQ series and put the messages directly on the queue. Web services are fully supported also, and VBScript is supported too,perhaps using QTPro for the script and a GUI user in LoadRunner?
Colin.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, as an alternative to a Web Services script, you could try recording a Windows Sockets script. I've used LoadRunner to record winsock scripts to test some (Java) APIs. What I did was write a really simple Java API client and then execute that from a Windows batch file. The batch file would then be referenced as the executable when recording a LR script in VUGen.

I'm not sure if VUGen can load a VBScript file for recording, but you might try. Otherwise, you might try wrapping your VBScript in a batch file that can be run by VUGen.

When VUGen records a winsock script, it's basically monitoring the network communication for the process you're recording with. After you're done recording, it'll generate a dump of the network data in a "data.ws" worksheet that you can look at and edit with VUGen. You can parameterize this data worksheet for your load tests.

Answer (score 0):

One can code SOA requests and parse responses within LoadRunner. 
See wilsonmar.com/1lrscript.htm.

But bear in mind that TCL and VBScript developed for functional testing have a different architecture and scope than LoadRunner scripts. QTP and WinRunner take over the application.

LoadRunner scripts focus on the exchange of data across the wire. In the case of headless SOA XML, this architectural distinction doesn't matter.

However, it may be easier for you to maintain VBscript from the GUI, because creating SOA scripts in LoadRunner require a deeper understanding of message formats than what most MQ developers have.

Answer (score 0):

You really have three paths for pushing and popping messages off of an MQ queue using LoadRunner

(1) MQTester.   This is a native MQ Protocol Add in for use with LoadRunner
(2) Winsock.  Winsock development is best described as tedipously similar to picking fly scat out of ground pepper.  Tedious, but in the end very rewarding.   Out of the box, no additional add ins are required except license updates (possibly)
(3) JMS using a Java Virtual user, see.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service .  You wind up with a small Java program in the Java template virtual user for LoadRunner.   You will have to deal with all of the Java black magic aspects associated with LoadRunner, but once you nail down the combination of release and installation details you can use the virtual same code to post to just about any JMS provider (not just MQ) with some connection factory settings changed.

You should be able to do JMS with the web services virtual user as well, but I have not tested that configuration.   Look at the JMS section of the run time settings.

Comment: OK, I'm with you on picking fly scat out of ground pepper being tedious but I never imagined it could be rewarding.  In fact, I never imagined that activity in any context before.  Thanks fo rwidening my horizons!  :-)